# How to make windows executable including dependencies for python 3.6

Tags: python-3.4, pyinstaller, py2exe

I have tried pyinstaller and py2exe (both are expected to work on python 3.4 environment), but pyinstaller is throwing error "No system module pywintypes.dll" and py2exe is throwing error (async def concat_async(async_gen): invalid syntax)

I have environment for python 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6
Help required!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Anaconda, try to put pywintypes.dll or pywintypes35.dll to folders:

```
 ...\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32
...\Continuum\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```